# Is there an easy way to traverse nested Shadow DOM when testing with Cucumber, Selenium & Capybara?

Tags: automated-tests, cucumber, capybara, aws-amplify, shadow-dom

I am attempting to write automation tests for the front-end UI of an app , that has a lot of nested shadow-doms and I am unable to access them using the Capybara, Cucumber & Selenium (using chromedriver). The app is using AWS Amplify Authenticator . I keep getting the following error when I try to find an input element :

`Unable to find css "input[id$='username']" (Capybara::ElementNotFound)`

This is what my test looks like:

`When('I type into the username field my {string}') do |string| find("input[id$='username']").set(string) end`

I have read on other posts that chrome driver supports shadow-doms but not sure how it would be handled in this scenario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you need to use `evaluate_script` to get access to the shadow-dom - like

```
element = find(...) # find element that contains shadow dom
shadow_root = @session.evaluate_script(<<~JS, element)
        (function(root){
          return root.shadowRoot;
        })(arguments[0])
      JS
shadow_root.find("input[id$='username']")
```

and then you can only use CSS based finders/actions/etc on the shadow DOM.

The WebDriver spec has been updated to bring more support for the shadow dom but it's not implemented in drivers yet - https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/#shadow-root